# Error from brownie compile with IERC721.sol

Tags: solidity, python, openzeppelin, brownie, solidity-0.8.x

I am getting an error from brownie compile and I can't figure out why it wont import one of the openzeppelin contracts when all the others import ok.
here is my brownie-config.yaml

```
# https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.3/config.html#exclude_paths
reports:
  exclude_contracts:
    - SafeMath
dependencies:
  # - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      # - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0'
```

And the code that is causing the issue:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Creator: Chiru Labs

pragma solidity >=0.8.12;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol';
```

and the results from brownie compile:

```
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.13
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source "/home/tonyr/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.1/openzeppelin-contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> contracts/ERC721A.sol:6:1:
  |
6 | import '@openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol';
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm at a loss as to why this one contract wont import when all the others seem to be ok?

Comment: There is something I don't understand, your error message doesn't match your source code:
`import '@openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol';` is different from
`import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol';`

Also in error message openzepellin version doesn't match the one in your configuration file: 4.4.1 & 4.5.0

Comment: I dont understand it either tbh...but its working now so I will close the question

Answer (score 0):

This is working now, without any changes. I dont have an explanation

Comment: The explanation is that you didn't delete your build folder... I nuked my system twice without realizing that is what causes this. Sometimes it gets corrupted.